# Typoscript: how to render subheader inside the header link (stdheader)?

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to render the HTML for headers and subheader when I have a link set for the header. Right now I have the following HTML being rendered:

```
<h1>
    <a href="/my-link/">Header Text</a>
    <small>Sub Header Text</small>
</h1>
```

### How do I do the following?

```
<h1>
    <a href="/my-link/">Header Text <small>Sub Header Text</small></a>
</h1>
```

Any help?

The current typoscript comes from the Bootstrap Package:

```
lib.stdheader {
    3 {
        headerClass {
            cObject {
                10 {
                    field = header_position
                    required = 1
                    noTrimWrap = |text-| |
                }
            }
        }
    }
    5 >
    10 >
    10 = CASE
    10 {
        setCurrent {
            field = header
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
            typolink.parameter.field = header_link
        }
        key {
            field = header_layout
            ifEmpty = {$content.defaultHeaderType}
            ifEmpty.override.data = register: defaultHeaderType
        }
        1 = COA
        1 {   
            10 = TEXT
            10.current = 1
            20 = TEXT
            20 {
                field = subheader
                stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | <small>|</small>|
                stdWrap.required = 1
            }

            stdWrap.dataWrap = <h1{register:headerClass}>|</h1>
            stdWrap.required = 1
        }
        (...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `typolink.parameter.field = header_link` to the `stdWrap.` at the bottom.